# ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heap-memory, objectspace

I'am trying to figure out `ObjectSpace.each_object`
In console:

```
class Foo; end  
Foo.new  
ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count  
=> 1  
GC.start  
ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count  
=> 1
```

I've seen examples and I know that the second count should be 0.
Any ideas what is going on here?
Thanks.

Comment: Why is count should be 0?

Comment: @Зелёный : Because Foo.new hasn't been assigned to any variable. Depending on the console, it could be out of reach and ready to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your console.

## IRB

The last result is saved as `_`, even if it hasn't been explicitely assigned.
Running `GC.start` won't remove the last object :

```
irb(main):001:0> class Foo; end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0>
irb(main):003:0* Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x007fca7a309f98>
irb(main):004:0> p ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count; GC.start; p ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count
1
1
=> 1
irb(main):005:0> p ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count; GC.start; p ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count
1
0
=> 0
```

## Pry

You can access the last result and the second to last result with `_` and `__` :

```
[1] pry(main)> 'a'
=> "a"
[2] pry(main)> 'b'
=> "b"
[3] pry(main)> p _, __
"b"
"a"
=> ["b", "a"]
```

Pry saves all the 100 last results in `_out_` Pry::HistoryArray:

```
[1] pry(main)> class Foo; end
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x007fd093102118>
[3] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count
=> 1
[4] pry(main)> GC.start
=> nil
[5] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count
=> 1
[6] pry(main)> _out_[2]
=> #<Foo:0x007fd093102118>
```

You can use `_out_.pop!` to remove its last element :

```
[1] pry(main)> class Foo; end
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x007fa90b1ad360>
[3] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count
=> 1
[4] pry(main)> GC.start
=> nil
[5] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count
=> 1
[6] pry(main)> 5.times{_out_.pop!}
=> 5
[7] pry(main)> GC.start
=> nil
[8] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count
=> 0
```

## Inside a script

If you execute :

```
class Foo; end

Foo.new
p ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count

GC.start
p ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count
```

inside a script, you get :

```
1
0
```

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation about _out_ ! Had a feeling its console related.

Comment: My pleasure. I actually never heard about `_out_` before.

Answer (score 0):

[`GC.start`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/GC.html#method-c-start) does not *force* the garbage collector to start.

It is slightly unclear from the documentation, but it just instructs the engine to *schedule* a garbage collection. That said, one can not rely on `GC.start` would immediately remove objects from the heap.

Comment: I am aware of it. Thank you,